# Ui for .net core 2.x

Tags: c#, uwp, .net-core

Is it possible to build a desktop UI for windows 10 that targets `.net core 2.x` or higher? I am running into problems. I have a class library targeting `.net core 2.1`.
And I would like to use the classes in that library within my windows 10 desktop app.

Comment: Is there a reason your class library isn’t targeting .NET Standard?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I decided to port my .net core 2.1 over to .net standard and now I can build a UI   with UWP. UWP at the moment targets  .net Standard 2.0 so will,work. I had to import some code using nuget as there was a problem with my use of Dynamic type with Cosmosdb but all working now.

Answer (score 5):

No there is no support for desktop UI in .net core 2.1 it was not the priority
It will be available in .net core 3.0 which will be released in 2019

But you can use [Avalonia UI](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia) which is in a beta version

BTW here are some improvements for desktop application when it will be released

1. Performance improvements and other runtime updates that will delight your users
2. Super easy to use or test a new version of .NET Core for just one app on a machine
3. Enables both machine-global and application-local deployment
4. Support for the .NET Core CLI tools and SDK-style projects in Visual Studio

   you can find more in  this [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/05/07/net-core-3-and-support-for-windows-desktop-applications/)

Answer (score 2):

If you're not using .net standard library, you have an option to convert your class library to .net standard [Convert .NET Core 2.0 class libraries to .NET Standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087573/convert-net-core-2-0-class-libraries-to-net-standard)  then use Universal Windows Platform (UWP) to build your ui. Windows Desktop App will be supported in .net core 3 next year.

.net standard: https://github.com/dotnet/standard

Comment: Thanks but I do not follow what you mean.Do you mean I will need to wait till .net core 3 ?

Comment: I mean, yes you can build your UI for .net core 2.x with Uwp you will need to learn how to build your ui using xaml.

Comment: @PaulStanley if you have an  urgent business you can start with Avalonia and later migrate to .net core 3.0

Comment: @Mac there  is no direct support for the desktop ui  in 2.x !